# Passing value while instantiating the view

Tags: swift

Need to adding a value from one view controller to another view controller via the following way. I successfully able to move to the another page but not able to passing the value

```
   sideMenuController?.cache(viewControllerGenerator: {
                self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "projectDetailController")
            }, with: "333")
            sideMenuController?.delegate = self as? SideMenuControllerDelegate

            sideMenuController?.setContentViewController(with: "333", animated: Preferences.shared.enableTransitionAnimation)
            sideMenuController?.hideMenu()
```

Comment: You can try to make a delegate for the second controller

Comment: How do i do this ? I have no idea

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property inside `ProjectDetailController`:

```
class ProjectDetailController: UIViewController {

    var someValue: String?

    /* more code */

}
```

Move the `ProjectDetailController` creation above and, once created - try to inject the value you want:

```
let projectDetailController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "projectDetailController") as! UINavigationController
let projectDetailViewController = projectDetailController.viewControllers.first as! ProjectDetailViewController
projectDetailViewController.projectId = id

sideMenuController?.cache(viewControllerGenerator: { projectDetailController }, with: "333")
sideMenuController?.delegate = self as? SideMenuControllerDelegate

sideMenuController?.setContentViewController(with: "333", animated:
Preferences.shared.enableTransitionAnimation)
sideMenuController?.hideMenu()
```

Comment: `projectDetailController ` is the UINavigationController not a ViewControlelr

Comment: So I need to passing the data through UINavigationController to the ViewController is it possible ?

Comment: Of course, just find the corresponding child view controller or the root one if only one child is on the stack. Are you saying ProjectDetailController is a NavigationController?

Comment: Yes ProjectDetailController is a NavigationController

Comment: Use viewController = projectDetailController.viewControllers.first as! YourViewController, then viewController.valueToBeInjected = someValue

Comment: It says Value of type 'ProjectDetailViewController' has no member 'viewControllers'

Comment: Glad to hear that!